# Why does Flutter SetState break my Animated Widget?

Tags: flutter

### The problem / mystery

I have these widgets on a normal page:

```
child: Stack(
  children: [
    AnimatedWidget(),
    StaticWidget(),
  ],
),
```

Notice, that there are an animated widget and a normal widget.

The layout of these widgets are working perfectly, but when SetState is called, the animated widget stops animating and does not respond to taps, which it should, because it is a button made in Rive.  In fact, it does not even output to console, that it has been pressed. However, when I press setState again, it prints the previous taps to console to sort of "catch up". There are no lagging or nothing else strange about this.

I am using Flutter 3.16.9, channel stable

## What I've tried

I noticed, that when I try to change the animated widget to use Container instead of SizedBox, it would fix it for this single time of calling SetState. Therefore, I got a janky solution, where I have a boolean, that gets changed on each build, and builds the animated widget differently each time like so:

```
Widget getAnimatedWidget(bool alternatedFix) {
  if (alternatedFix) {
    //build with Container()
  } else {
    //build with SizedBox()
  }
}
```

If they both used Container, it would not work, but with them being different, it works. They are visually the exact same.

### Help needed

I would appreciate any help, that you can provide, so I can understand this problem. Does it have a simpler solution?

Comment: may sharing ur code would do better

Answer (score 1):

Try to set a unique key for your `AnimatedWidget`. e.g. `AnimatedWidget(key: UniqueKey())`.

Without unique key, anytime you call `setState`, you'll build a new `AnimatedWidget`.

Comment: I did not try this, but it was a good suggestion. However, it did not fix the problem.